# Split snowflake db columns based on a delimiter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

got a bit stuck with SPLIT condition and looking for a hand with how to get the result

got a string:

```
03::AccountID:23.04.2019;;AccountNum:1234567;;ActiveDate:Jan  1 1900 12:00AM;;BankAccount:12;11;
```

The formatting condition is ColumnName:NewValue;OldValue;

result wanted is:

| COLUMN_N | OLD_VALU | NEW_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AccountID | 23.04.2019 |  |
| AccountNum | 1234567 |  |
| ActiveDate | Jan 1 1900 12:00AM |  |
| BankAccount | 12 | 11 |

Thanks all for help!

So far I've tried multiple CTE's with latteral split based on different delimiter but found it difficult to get around where the new column name begins

Comment: Hi - you just need a separate SPLIT for each delimiter. So if you split by : first then you take that output, get the element from the array that still has multiple fields and SPLIT that again with the ; delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not as easy as it looks - it need multiple level of splits.

1. replaced :: by ;; so that all columns have same delimitter.
2. Then splitted them based on ;;
3. split last column based on ;

```
select split(table1.value,':')[0] COLUMN_N,split(split(table1.value,':')[1],';')[0] old 
,split(split(table1.value,':')[1],';')[1] new
    from table(split_to_table( replace('03::AccountID:23.04.2019;;AccountNum:1234567;;ActiveDate:Jan  1 1900 12:00AM;;BankAccount:12;11;','::',';;'), ';;')) as table1
    order by table1.value
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roy!  Let me try your version.  and no, it's not as easy as it looks  :)