# Split snowflake db string based on a delimiter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

got a string

```
AccountID, ÿþ 23.04.2019 ÿþ  ÿþ AccountNum, ÿþ 68 ÿþ  ÿþ ActiveDate, ÿþ Jan  1 1900 12:00AM ÿþ  ÿþ BankAccount, ÿþ  ÿþ  ÿþ BankAccountType, ÿþ 0 ÿþ 1 ÿþ BankCIN, ÿþ  ÿþ  ÿþ BankCodeType, ÿþ 0 ÿþ 0 ÿþ BankConstantSymbol, ÿþ 0 ÿþ  ÿþ BankContractAccount, ÿþ  ÿþ  ÿþ BankGroupID, ÿþ  ÿþ  ÿþ BankIBAN, ÿþ  ÿþ  ÿþ CellularPhone, ÿþ 123 ÿþ 321 ÿþ ContactPerson
```

text format is
[ColumnName], ÿþ [OldValue] ÿþ [NewValue] ÿþ

Required result is

[image]

Thanks for any pointers!

Tried replacing the delimiter with split_to_table, tried split_part...keep getting stuck on the time from activedate. Then I assumed since I could split_to_table I'll use LAG or LEAD to get the following index value as a column...but got stuck.

Comment: I think you will struggle to do this in SQL as the data structure is not consistent - there is no placeholder when there is no data value so you have nothing to indicate that a column “value” needs to be created at those places in the data. I think you would have to do this in code - possibly as a function returning a table, depending on how you want to use the result

Comment: you can extend this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419389/split-snowflake-db-columns-based-on-a-delimiter/75426229#75426229 . All you have to do is increase position of second row, third row etc.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I'm wondering how you would split the string? If you split it on the comma then you would start with AccountID on its own and then its field values will get associated to the next column i.e. "AccountID", "ÿþ 23.04.2019 ÿþ  ÿþ AccountNum", "ÿþ 68 ÿþ  ÿþ ActiveDate". you can't split on spaces (as some of the values have embedded spaces) and I can't see how splitting on ÿþ, for example, would help?

Comment: @KoushnikRoy, sorry Roy, would you be ok to change the query the way you've suggested for the new string? I think split to table with replacing was...is a bit out of my leage just yet to know how to use it on my particular situation? Massive thanks for your time with this guys! Been working my way through it for a couple of days.

Comment: @NickW, i agree, but i think if you use ÿþ as delimiter, separate all elements out. And then combine 3 elements using split_to table and create rows with them. I dont have a working solution but i think this will work since all elements are separated by ÿþ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
WITH SPLIT_DATA AS (
SELECT 
-- Each group of 3 values will form the same row
ceil(index/3) ROW_ID 
-- label each element as to which column in each row it should be assigned to
, case when mod(index,3) = 0 then 3 else mod(index,3) end pos
-- Remove the trailing comma from the column name values
, CASE WHEN RIGHT(TRIM(VALUE),1) = ',' THEN LEFT(TRIM(VALUE),LENGTH(TRIM(VALUE))-1) ELSE TRIM(VALUE) END VALUE
FROM COMPLEX_SPLIT, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(LONG_STRING,'ÿþ ')
),
PIVOT_DATA AS (
SELECT *
FROM SPLIT_DATA
    PIVOT(MIN(VALUE) FOR POS IN (1, 2, 3))
    AS p (ROW_ID, COLUMN_NAME, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE)
)
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE
FROM PIVOT_DATA
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
;
```

Comment: Massive thanks Nick!!! Let me try to convert it to my query!  
I've been testing very similar, lateral with pivot afterwards